# Buffered File writes

Tags: c++, file-io, buffer

I am working on a log collection c++ program.

When logs are received, they are processed and written to a file. I want to optimize the performance by reducing the overhead in the file-write operation; especially when the logs are being sent at a high rate.

After some web research, I have come to know that I can reduce the overhead by writing a chunk of data at once. I am thinking of storing a certain amount of logs in some buffer and writing the contents of the buffer when the buffer size exceeds some certain value; then empty the buffer and repeat.

How do I determine the optimum value for the buffer size?

Comment: Profile your buffering code using different buffer sizes until you achieve performance that suits your needs.  Typically, ideal buffer sizes should be an even multiple of 512b/1K, or whatever your disk drive's sector size is set to. [Microsoft recommands 64K](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc938632(v=technet.10)).

Comment: How can I make it a more generic solution?  The buffer size has to be optimum on any machine the program is run and the logs are being sent all the time. So there are no particular CPU-RAM specifications and conditions in which to profile in order to get the 'accurate' optimum value. How can I find the optimum buffer size using code(assuming its not too much of a trouble).

Comment: You need to consider this very carefully. The objective of a log file isn't just maxmum write speed.You also have to think about how much data you can afford to lose in the event of a crash. You are quite likely to lose the log events that give the reason for the crash.

Comment: @user207421 I am not clearly getting what you have mentioned. My program is supposed to collect logs of other applications. So if my program crashes that doesn't mean that the logs are lost right? Only the collected copies of logs are lost. Am I wrong?